# Log4j in Lotus Domino

Tags: log4j, using, lotus, lotus-domino

We are using Log4j.xml for the layout preferences while logging using log4j.jar... 
I have developed a common class which reads this XML file and logs info or error ... 
In this class I have a method that accepts the path to the config file... 
For test on my local, I saved it to my temp space and pointed the loger class to look there... 
on my server, this file is again planned to be placed in some directory and pass the path... 
My question is, should this be a path (similar to jvm/lib/ext for jar files) in the server's file system in the notes installation directory or any path should be fine?

Answer (score 1):

On the Domino server you may place files to an arbitrary path and access them later from your code.

There is an important point you need to keep in mind.

Accessing the filesystem is a restricted operation. And your server agent that invokes filesystem operations has to be allowed to execute the restricted operations.

It can be done via "Security" tab in the domino agent settings.